# When running Node server I get the error "Change the require to a dynamic import()"

Tags: nodes

```
C:\Users\chris\servertest\signal-server\src>node server.js
C:\Users\chris\servertest\signal-server\src\server.js:5
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');
                   ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\chris\servertest\signal-server\node_modules\nanoid\index.js from C:\Users\chris\servertest\signal-server\src\server.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\chris\servertest\signal-server\src\server.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chris\servertest\signal-server\src\server.js:5:20) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
```

I got this error, how can I solve this?

Comment: The error is "Change the require to a dynamic import()" - did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the library using ES6 concept

```
import {nanoid} from 'nanoid';
```

Comment: imported like this: const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');